# Swift UIActivityViewController Email subject line inherits global UINavigationBar font change

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I change the size and weight of the `UINavigationBar` font with the following:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: .heavy)]
```

When I present the `UIActivityViewController` and select Mail, the subject line in the title (not the email) inherits the font change.  In order to change this, I change the `UINavigationBar` back to something smaller.

While this works, and the subject line in the title is smaller, and now readable, when the `UIActivityViewController` returns, naturally the `UINavigationBar` font is still set to the new size and weight.  I tried the completion as per below, but the font doesn't resize.

```
@objc func showActivityViewController() {

     UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
     UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .thin)]

     present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {

          UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
          UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: .heavy)]

        })
    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot and the version of iOS?

Comment: iOS 11.1, screenshot coming

Answer (score 0):

I change the font color of a `UIButton` in a similar way. I found that using the main thread helped. Try this and see if it works:

```
 present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
          UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: .heavy)]
      }
 })
```